# xml formattin in SQL select statements

Tags: sql-server, xml, tags

if i want to display the person_id and level_name with a hyphen in the middle when the where not exists condition works but the msg shows xml tags e.g. `<person_ID>104</person_ID>A2001` .
How do I get rid of the tags ?

```
DECLARE @level_name nvarchar(MAX) =
        (
        SELECT [person_ID],'-',
                     [level_NAME]+ '  '
        FROM inserted ic 
        where not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[levels] c 
                                      WHERE ic.[geo]=c.[GEO] and 
                   and c.area=1)
                      FOR XML PATH('')
         );

    IF @level_name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('level name not found : %s', 16, 1, @level_name) with log;
        END;
```

Comment: why u using `FOR XML PATH` ? And Why not add all string into one, like this: `[person_ID] + '-' + [level_NAME]+ '  '`

Comment: I am new to xml not sure how else if I dont user xml path . This path returns multiple unmatched results at once .This code sort of taken care of the issue , `SELECT concat ([person_ID],'-', [LEVEL_NAME])
   + '  '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with something before the element person_id like this:

```
DECLARE @level_name nvarchar(MAX) =
        (
        SELECT '' + [person_ID],'-',
                     [level_NAME]+ '  '
        FROM inserted ic 
        where not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[levels] c 
                                      WHERE ic.[geo]=c.[GEO] and 
                   and c.area=1)
                      FOR XML PATH('')
         );

    IF @level_name IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('level name not found : %s', 16, 1, @level_name) with log;
        END;
```

a basic test for this solution is:

```
    SELECT ''+[person_ID],'-',
                 [level_NAME]+ '  '
    FROM (select 1 AS person_id, 'l' AS level_name) ic 
                  FOR XML PATH('')
```

compared to

```
    SELECT [person_ID],'-',
                 [level_NAME]+ '  '
    FROM (select 1 AS person_id, 'l' AS level_name) ic 
                  FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: still getting the same output `<person_ID>105</person_ID>-A2001 `

Comment: I added an example to clarify the solution showing the effect of adding ''+ before person_id

Comment: THANKS THIS GIVES ME WHAT I ORIGINALY WANTED .